# Java NoClassDefFoundError despite set classpath

Tags: java, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I have some trouble with getting a Java application to run in the console and/or with Ant.
I know that a lot of starting issues are related to the classpath being not set or incorrectly set, though I'm fairly sure I set it correctly, so my search only yielded results on that.

Here is the general setup of my application:
classes are in packages model, view and controller. controller.Controller is the class with the main method. I am using objectdb as my JPA provider.

I am using Ant to compile my application.

After compiling, I can run my application from ant with the following script:

```
<target name="run" description="default build process">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

where ${main-class} is controller.Controller and classpath consists of /lib and /dist folders (the application's jar file is compiled to /dist)

Now I tried copying all .jar files from /lib and /dist to one separate folder and run them with`java -jar cooking.jar -cp .` which results in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at model.jpa.JPAModelFactory.<init>(JPAModelFactory.java:28)
    at model.jpa.JPAModelFactory.<init>(JPAModelFactory.java:24)
    at controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:59)
    at controller.Controller.main(Controller.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

So I tried ant and slightly modified above build target to:

```
<target name="run2" description="default build process">
    <java fork="true" jar="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

which results in the same error. I don't understand why.

Just to test it, I tried running from the command line by specifying the main class directly: `java -cp . controller.Controller` which for some reason cannot even locate the class (it's there, I confirmed it):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: controller/Controller
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controller.Controller
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: controller.Controller.  Program will exit.
```

I have set JAVA_HOME to my JDK's path, and CLASSPATH to my JRE's/lib path.
OS is Windows 7 64 bit, Java version is 1.6.0_25-b06

I am puzzled by two things:
a) Why is Java unable to locate controller.Controller, even though it is present in the .jar file and the .jar file is in the current directory?
b) What am I doing wrong that calling Java with -jar seems to mess up the lookup mechanisms.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you see in your Manifest.MF file for the class-path and Main-class entry?

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.0-b11 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: controller.Controller

Answer (score 2):

The class path should consist of

1. directories with class files (in their proper package directory)
2. jar files.

You cannot point the class path to a directory of jars. Things are different when running a application server (eg Tomcat), which will load jars from a directory for you.

Answer (score 1):

> though I'm fairly sure I set it correctly

The evidence is against you.  The JVM is telling you that you have not set it correctly.

What do you think that ref 'classpath' pointing to?  Where do you assume its values are coming from?   They should be defined inside the Ant build.xml, right?  Like this:

```
<path id="production.class.path">
    <pathelement location="${production.classes}"/>
    <pathelement location="${production.resources}"/>
    <fileset dir="${production.lib}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        <exclude name="**/junit*.jar"/>
        <exclude name="**/*test*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="test.class.path">                            
    <path refid="production.class.path"/>
    <pathelement location="${test.classes}"/>
    <pathelement location="${test.resources}"/>
    <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
        <include name="**/junit*.jar"/>
        <include name="**/*test*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

If you're creating an executable JAR, you need to specify the main class and classpath in the manifest, as CoolBeans correctly pointed out in the comment.  The 3rd party JAR locations have to be relative to the executable JAR.  You should package them with your executable JAR in such a way that the relative path is easy to sort out and understand.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I did specify the main class in the manifest as can be seen in my comment above. Also, in the ant-file classpath points to two folders ("and classpath consists of /lib and /dist folders (the application's jar file is compiled to /dist)". I would post the definition of my build file here, but the comment section doesn't format things nicely. There are no jar-locations in the manifest file however. I thought that this is what the -cp switch is for? If this is not enough, then how do I set the locations in the manifest?

Comment: -cp is the command line way to specify classpath.  Ant has no effect on your JAR file at runtime - it's a build tool.  Sounds like you'd better learn how to set classpath in the manifest of your JAR: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: I know that Ant is just a built tool. And I know what the -cp switch is used for, it's not my first Java application :) I thought that I do not need to set any classpath within the jar file, if I specify it with -cp (which I do). I also tried adding a Class-Path: entry to the manifest - no change.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this happens when I specify **both** the `<classpath>` and the `jar="..."` in the target.  I removed the `jar="..."`, placed that `.jar` into the `<classpath>` list and it ran after that.